# How to match a regular expression from a SQL table to a text

Tags: sql, regex

I have used before LIKE command to match patterns to a specific SQL table column. For example need all the rows which all have name started with "A". But this case I am trying to solve things reversed , have a column "Description" where all the regular expressions row wise. And need to return specific rows which all match with a input text.

```
Table A
Description
============
\b[0-9A-Z ]*WT[A-Z0-9 ]*BALL\b
\b[0-9A-Z ]*WG[A-Z0-9 ]*BAT\b
\b[0-9A-Z ]*AX[A-Z0-9 ]*BAR\b
```

So Description column has these regular expressions and the input text "BKP 200 WT STAR BALL" So need to return the first row after select query since that the only match. If any one can help with the select query or idea, would be very helpful. If more details required please mention also.

Comment: Please share with do you use Oracle, SQLServer or maybe MySQL or something else ?

Comment: SQL server which is inbuilt in .net framework

Answer (score 0):

Cross join you regex table to one that you searching within. Then just match two columns against each other.

[Here's the example how you can match any of your expressions](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6KnZMi2nmzAhHwtAdtr9dk/2).

[Here how you can match all of them](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6KnZMi2nmzAhHwtAdtr9dk/6)

Comment: Any other alternatives? since don't have much scope to incorporate the input text into a new table for the cross join, however the idea seems interesting and worth trying.

Comment: @RahulCoffee if you have one or a small amount of values select your regexes, then your input as constant as many times as you need to compare, separated with comma. If there are many inputs create temporary table or CTE and cross join it.